# How do I check if an object's children (and their children, infinite levels) are undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the below object, I want to create a function that can determine if any field in the tree has an undefined values. I need the function to traverse infinitely (or walk this tree of objects) when checking for undefined.

```
myObject: {
 myCoolField: "Here is my value.",
 myAwesomeField: undefined,
 myRadField: {
   radA: true,
   radB: false,
   radC: {
     anotherOne: undefined,
     yetAnother: 'A random string.'
   }
 }
}
```

I've attempted this trying to leverage `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myObject))` however I've only been able to get that to check the first level of fields.

Comment: @ElvisPimentel what exactly is unclear about this?  It seems clear: it's asking how to recursively walk an object tree and check if anything in that tree has any undefined properties.

Comment: @ElvisPimentel I have updated the question and added an example object. Can we consider re-opening this? Also, if you have any advice on this I would appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check the object tree recursively and do whatever you want with `undefined` keys.

```
function fn(object) {
  if (typeof object === 'undefined') {
      // do something
      return;
  }
  for (let key in object) {
      if (typeof object[key] === 'undefined') {
          // do something
          delete object[key];  // delete undefined if you want
      }
      if (typeof object[key] === 'object') {
          // do something
          fn(object[key]); // recursive call to check undefined values
      }
  }
};
```

Input:

```
const myObject= {
  myCoolField: "Here is my value.",
  myAwesomeField: undefined,
  myRadField: {
    radA: true,
    radB: false,
    radC: {
      anotherOne: undefined,
      yetAnother: 'A random string.'
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  myCoolField: 'Here is my value.',
  myRadField: { radA: true, radB: false, radC: { yetAnother: 'A random string.' } }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is actually very useful to me and I really appreciate your reply. No idea why you got downvoted or what the deal is with the harsh criticism on this particular question or your response, but thank you.